# Запись метаданных в Html файл

Tags: java, html, mp3

Как вывести метаданные в html файл?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        String fileLocation = "D:\\music";
        File dir = new File(fileLocation);
        readFiles(dir);

    }




    public static void readFiles(File baseDirectory){

        try {
            if(baseDirectory.isDirectory()) {

                for (File fileloop : baseDirectory.listFiles()) {
                    if(fileloop.isFile()) {

                        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileloop);
                        ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
                        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                        Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                        ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
                        parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
                        input.close();

                        String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

                        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println("Title: " + toHtml(metadata.get("title")));
                        System.out.println("Artists: " + toHtml(metadata.get("xmpDM:artist")));
                        System.out.println("Album : " + toHtml(metadata.get("xmpDM:album")));
                        System.out.println("Duration : " + toHtml(toMinutes(metadata.get("xmpDM:duration"))));
                        System.out.println("Path : " + toHtml(fileloop.getAbsolutePath()));
                    }
                    else{
                        readFiles(fileloop);
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TikaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String toMinutes(String timeInMilis) {
        double milis = Double.valueOf(timeInMilis);
        long second = (long) (milis / 1000) % 60;
        long minute = (long) (milis / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
        long hour = (long) (milis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
        return hour != 0 ? String.format("%02dh:%02dm:%02ds", hour, minute, second) : String.format("%02dm:%02ds", minute, second);
    }
```

Я создавал html файл и заполнял его вот как на скрине 
[image: html file]

и создавал метод

```
public static String  toHtml (String htmlData) throws IOException {

        File htmlTemplateFile = new File("D:\\music\\HtmlMusic.html");
        String htmlString = FileUtils.readFileToString(htmlTemplateFile);
        htmlString = htmlString.replace("$body", htmlData);
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(htmlTemplateFile,htmlString);
        return toHtml(htmlString);
    }
```

В итоге получается выводить только имя мп3 файла а дальше ошибки, я так понял это из-за того что я заменяю $body а он только один.Может можно как нибудь сделать легче?

Просто в методе `toHtml` надо было кое что исправить
вот

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newHtmlFile,htmlString,true);
```

и все заработало

Comment: Не знаю как в `Java` дела обстоят, но вы можете записать данные в массив, объединить в строку и сделать замену? Судя по коду, `HtmlData` уже должна содержать в себе все нужные данные.

Comment: выше в коде все есть, я не могу в коммент скинуть большую часть кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки у вас из-за того, что место возврата строки вы вызываете рекурсию.
Если вы хотете просто вывести на экран html код со вставленным значением, то в методе `toHtml` надо написать `return htmlString;`

Comment: Сделал так, все ровно в html файл выводится только одно(название/исполнитель)

Comment: Да, конечно, вы же в эту функцию передаете только 1 название. Либо передавайте туда массив из строк и уже в методе соединяйте их в 1 строчку разделяя например тегом `<br>`(лучше через StringBuilder для оптимизации), либо сразу передавайте туда строку со всеми соединеными значениями

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали получилось (код ниже скинул), но теперь метаданные записываются только из подкаталога, а метаданные файлов которые в корне не записывает

Answer (score 0):

Вот собственно код, но метаданные записываются только тех файлов которые находятся в подкаталоге(возможно потому что он первый в корне папке) а метаданные файлов которые лежат в корне не записывает

```
public static void readFiles(File baseDirectory){

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if(baseDirectory.isDirectory()) {
                for (File fileloop : baseDirectory.listFiles()) {
                    if(fileloop.isFile()) {

                        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileloop);
                        ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
                        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                        Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                        ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
                        parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
                        input.close();
                        String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();
                        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Title: ") .append(metadata.get("title"));
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Artist: ").append(metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Album : ").append(metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Duration : ").append(toMinutes(metadata.get("xmpDM:duration")));
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Path : ");
                        sb.append("<a href= > ");
                        sb.append(fileloop.getAbsolutePath());
                        sb.append("</a>");
                        String result = sb.toString();
                        toHtml(result);
                    }
                    else{
                        readFiles(fileloop);
                    }
                }
            }
```